# On addThis enabled ajax page browser back button is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, addthis

In my ajax page browser back button is not working because of addthis plugin

```
$.ajax({
            url: "http://s7.addthis.com/js/250/addthis_widget.js?pub=ra-4f6796df59a35f6c",
            dataType: 'script',
            success: function () {
                var addthis_config = {
                    "data_track_addressbar": true
                };
            }
            });
```

Above is the code which we are using to call the addthis script.If i comment the above code it is working, Can anyone help on this?

Comment: What's the page where you're seeing the problem?

Comment: The problem is with only firefox and at the first click its not going back to the previous page but for the second click, so i think hash url is pushed two times into the browser history.

Comment: Back buttons seems to work fine if I click around the site - I did notice on the first page load, there was a "Detecting cookies" page that redirected me to another page, which adds to your browser history, so that if you pressed back, it wouldn't work.